# Is there a way to run a service a set time after Windows starts?

Tags: windows, boot, services

I  have a program that works as a service and works with the network on a low level. It appears that a service it starts too early, so I want to configure it so that it starts after Windows starts, ie after all the stuff in the Registry etc are started.

I am thinking along the lines of the Windows equivalent of /etc/rc.local in Linux, or even after /etc/rc.local has run.

Any ideas

/vfclistsGUY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For services and drives on Windows you can specify dependencies to other services which will delay the startup of your service.

[How to delay loading of specific services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888/en-us)

Additionally since Vista there is the new startup type "Automatic (delayed)" which delays the service startup until most of the other services has been started.